# Как запустить тесты Rspec на Ruby без запуска самого Ruby приложения?

Tags: ruby, test-driven-development, rspec

Имеется такой rspec файл:

```
--require spec_helper
--format documentation
```

Содержание spec_helper:

```
require "./caesar_cipher"
require "./stock_picker"
require "./substrings"
```

Соответственно для каждого из ruby файла существует "spec/*_spec.rb" файл. При вводе в терминале команды `rspec` помимо тестов запускаются сначала также сами ruby файлы. Как сделать чтобы запускались только тесты?

Comment: Эм... не запускать эти файлы в `spec_helper`'е? Или речь не об этих "ruby файлах"?

Comment: @D-side речь об этих самых "ruby файлах", как сделать, чтобы тесты знали об их существовании, но сам их код не запускали?

Comment: Если в этих файлах объявления, то чтобы загрузить их, эти файлы нужно выполнить. Без вариантов.

Comment: @D-side А как тогда быть при работе с крупными проектами? Каждый раз ждать выполнения всей программы, когда просто нужно пропустить её через тесты?

Comment: Нет, необязательно. Но здесь вы делаете именно это. Сложно что-то посоветовать кроме "не делайте это". Хотя чтобы протестировать программу, да, её код придется выполнить. Много раз. Потому что вы, вообще-то, проверяете результаты его выполнения. Возможно, я сейчас сыплю очевидностями, но пока что я попросту не понимаю, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: @D-side Тогда поставлю свой вопрос так: мне надо, чтобы в терминале выходили только результаты тестов, без output самой программы.

Comment: В зависимости от того, какой вид тестов вы хотите – тестируйте модули, которые вводом-выводом не занимаются и/или запускайте вашу программу в подпроцессе внутри тестов (см. документацию к модулю `Open3`, например).

Comment: @D-side Чтобы протестировать отдельный модуль надо прописать require <имя модуля>, я правильно понял?

Comment: Надо выполнить файл, в котором он находится. Если у вас модули разложены по файлам, то да.

Comment: @D-side, спасибо я понял, вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прислушался к @D-side и Разобрался, объединил все три ruby файла в один: `usefull_things.rb`, в нём все функции объединил в один модуль `UsefullThings`. Соответственно файл `spec_helper.rb` стал выглядить так:

```
require "./usefull_things"
include UsefullThings
```

Убрал весь `output` в самих функциях, если захочу их использовать, то создам отдельный ruby файл включу туда этот модуль и вызову их.

Также недавно узнал ещё один способ пропускать код через тесты без `output`. Надо включить библиотеку в `spec` файл `require 'active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting'` и обернуть проверку функции с `output` вот так:

```
     it "show a pole" do
       output = capture(:stdout) do
         $pole.show
       end
       expect(output).to be_instance_of String
     end
```